# Your render method should have return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these object data like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "obj1": {
      "val1": "15",
      "val2": "2.6"
    },
    "obj2": {
      "val3": "39",
      "val4": "87"
    },
    "arr1": [
      {
        "ar1": "nd",
        "ar11": "https://url"
      },
      {
        "ar1": "eeh",
        "ar11": "url"
      }
    ],
    "arr2": [
      {
        "l1": "land",
        "l2": "re"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I passed these data from parent component to child component through props and I tried to use map to iterate and render output like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Output extends Component {

    render() {
          const myobj = this.props;        
          console.log(myobj);
          Object.keys(myobj).map(function(key) {
             return( <div>Key: {key}, Value: {myobj[key]}</div> );
          });
    }
}

export default Output;
```

But I get that `render` must have a return statement so how I should write this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return you have is inside `.map` function. But it doesn't return in the `render`. You just need to return the returned array from `.map`

```
// this return is inside render
return Object.keys(myobj).map(function(key) {
    // this return is inside .map
    return( <div>Key: {key}, Value: {myobj[key]}</div> );
});
```

## EDIT:

You should take a look at [ivica.moke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7615691/ivica-moke) comment, you will have errors because you can't render objects.

I'm not sure what you want to do because in your question, you only mention the problem where `render must have a return statement`.

So please explain what you want to do when the value is an object an how you want to render it.

## EDIT 2:

If you want to visualize what is inside the object, you can try `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)`

Comment: And, because some of keys have object as a value, it will throw him an error that he cannot render objects, he needs to do some deeper check for that.

Comment: yes I get now the "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id,"

Comment: @Wel you are getting this error because of what ivica.moke said. You haven't said how you want to render your values when it's an object, please explain that

Comment: I just want to display keys and values for all objects for example inside <li></li>

Comment: Sorry I forgot I need to iterate through as well

Answer (score 0):

`render()` method need to return some `jsx` inorder to show that in view. `.map` is returning the `jsx` but it is not returned to `render` method. Added `return` statement

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

        class Output extends Component {

            render() {
              const myobj = this.props;

                 console.log(myobj);
                  return Object.keys(myobj).map(function(key) {
                      return( <div>Key: {key}, Value: {myobj[key]}</div> );
                  });

          }
       }
       export default Output;
```